# Where do I install the bootloader on a 2 drive computer?

Tags: dual-boot

I have 2 hard drives so they are sda and sdb.  Win7 is installed on the sdb and the sda drive is simply storage as the sda drive was added later.  In this case would I install the bootloader on the windows drive (sdb) or the storage drive (sda) - where the installer wants to install the bootloader by default?

Comment: You install bootloader on the drive you are going to boot from.

Comment: @Zanna - He needs help installing GRUB.

Comment: The Setup should handle this automatically, however you will not be able to boot directly into windows without your disk that contains GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

**You should install it to the drive with Windows 7. (`/dev/sdb`)**

The reason is because that way the installer will replace the Windows bootloader with GRUB. Otherwise, each drive would have a bootloader, with wouldn't be optimal. It could be confusing later on. Although, do take note both configs will work.

If you were to install GRUB to your data drive, you would have to mess with the boot order whenever you wanted to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Why? Can you explain?

Comment: @Pilot6 - Edited.

Comment: It is OK to have bootloaders on both drives. This way it is possible to switch OS in BIOS or in boot menu.

Comment: @Pilot6 - It wouldn't be optimal for me (As I said in my answer). Feel free to create your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter much where you install grub.

The point is to install it to the drive you plan to boot Ubuntu from.

If you install grub to `sdb` and boot from it, you will have an option in grub menu to boot into Windows or Ubuntu.

If you install grub to `sda` and boot from `sdb`, you will boot into Windows.

If you install grub to `sda` and boot from `sda` you will have a choice between Windows and Ubuntu. That menu can also be hidden, if you like to choose OS from BIOS or its boot menu.

So both choices are good enough.

And also you can always move grub from one drive to another later.